# Why might a oui.txt file have appeared in my home directory on my MBP?

Tags: macos, file

*oui.txt* has "suddenly" appeared. I don't know how/why.

It's 4.1MB, so it's probably this: https://linuxnet.ca/ieee/oui/

> Sanitized oui.txt Wed, 12 Feb 2020 03:10:16 -0400  •  4.1 MB (4,050,564 bytes)  •  ASCII

The result of `ls -le@ oui.txt`is:

```
$: ls -le@ oui.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user staff 4047610 31 Jan 12:20 oui.txt
        com.apple.TextEncoding 15
```

Comment: Have you run any software / web-based network mapping apps lately?

Comment: @klanomath
 com.apple.TextEncoding      15

Comment: @JonnyNott In my opinion it's related to some dev tool (e.g. `npm oui`), a network tool like Wireshark or nmap or some misdirected php command (downloading oui.txt to your home folder accidentially).

Comment: I've deleted it. Hopefully all will be ok!

Answer (score 1):

I have a file on my computer named utils6.py. The top of the file has this comment section.

> This file is part of Scapy  See http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy
>   for more informations  Copyright (C) Philippe Biondi 
>   This program is published under a GPLv2 license
>
> Copyright (C) 2005  Guillaume Valadon 
>   Arnaud Ebalard

The code has Utility functions for IPv6.

This utility script outputs a file called oui.txt